# What are some alternatives to ImageMagick for resizing gifs?

Tags: image, imagemagick, gif, graphicsmagick

Currently using a Node.js wrapper for ImageMagick to resize Gifs (gm).

However many of the Gifs glitch in various ways. Majority of them are fine, but a significant enough percentage (around 20) glitch.

What are some alternatives to ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick?

Comment: Do you have some examples that glitch to share?

Comment: What command did you use with ImageMagick? Can you provide the command line and the image. I suspect you are not processing the gif properly in ImageMagick if it is an animated gif.

Comment: CONTINUED: Did you try: convert input.gif -coalesce -resize XXX -layers optimize result.gif

Answer (score 0):

How about [images.weserv.nl](http://images.weserv.nl)? An image resizing CDN.

Answer (score -1):

Can I spam my own service? It can resize animated GIFs: https://gifsonic.com/home/